# How to save rich data into mongoDB for creating a blog?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular-cli, blogs, angular-fullstack

I am trying to build my own blog using NodeJS and angular Cli, and I have a question on how to save rich blog data in my MongoDB.

My data in MongoDB is following:

```
const blogSchema = new Schema({ 
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
    },
  body: {
   type: String,
   required: true
   },
  createdBy: {
   type: String
   }
})
```

For example, The output to HTML is

```
{{blog.body}}
```

Now, there is a blog, blog.body contains two paragraphs. HTML input as follows: (and save to the database).

```
There is example text.

There is a second text.
```

The display on the HTML become "There is example text. There is a second text."

I tried to insert HTML tag "\n" or "" between this two paragraphs, but not work. It displays as "There is example text. \n There is a second text."

How to make it show as a proper format on the HTML page?
Is there anything I miss?

Comment: It did not solve my problem. I provide the example now. Hope it explains my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a

`<br>`

between the two lines?

Comment: I did, but not work. Here is my test result on the webpage.    Try to get different paragraph. <br> <p>This is one example.</p> /n This is the second example. not work!!!!